# nokogiri: wrap <tbody> around <table>'s child

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

how can i do this ? i need to place tbody after table tags, basically to emulate Firefox's behavior.

i done this:

```
nodes = @doc.css "table > *"
wrapper = nodes.wrap("<tbody></tbody>")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<tbody>` should be only be used to wrap the body of your table, so assuming you have no header or footer, this will work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA)
html.xpath('//table').each do |htable|
  tbody = html.create_element('tbody')
  tbody.children = htable.children
  htable.children = tbody
end

puts html.xpath('//table').to_s

__END__
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</table>
```

prints

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><tbody>
<tr><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data3</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```